# Error on reload for MERN stack app hosted on heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, mern, reload

I created a MERN stack chat app and uploaded it to heroku and it works fine for the most part however anytime I refresh a page I get an error

```
`{"message":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/frontend/a-townhall/build/index.html'","stack":null}`
```

I've tried upgrading to a paid dyno, changing the path to the build file and reuploading the build file but nothing works. This is what I currently have in my server.js

```
`const __dirname1 = path.resolve();
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname1, "/frontend/a-townhall/build")));

    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname1, "/frontend/a-townhall/build", "index.html"));
    });
} else {
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
        res.send("API up and running away");
    });
}`
```

Comment: "I've tried upgrading to a paid dyno"—why would that have any effect? And aren't all dynos now paid?

Comment: "heroku-postbuild": "cd ./frontend/a-townhall && npm install --force && npm run build"  and this is the heroku postbuild in my package. Json